# Update column with id value of current row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need to set a query like below:

```
UPDATE A
    SET Column = (CASE WHEN (Select COUNT(*) from A, B
                             where A.Id = B.Id ) > 0 THEN 1
                       WHEN (Select COUNT(*) from A, B
                             where A.Id = B.bId ) > 10 THEN 2
                  END)
```

I need to do this with id value of current row in table. But I don't know how to get this value.
This code

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A, B
WHERE A.Id = B.Id
```

returns result for all rows, but I need a result for current row.

I use SQL Server

Comment: There's something wrong. the second case intend when count is equals to 0? Right?

Comment: But count(*) is counting the number of rows in this query, what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: @FernandoGarcia , I need to count rows for which id for current updated row = id from another table

Comment: Absolutely unclear, what is requirement...

Answer (score 0):

I think (if I've understood your requirements correctly) something like the following will work for you

```
  UPDATE upd
     SET upd.[Column] = case when inlineTbl.CountResult  > 10 then 2
                             else 1 end
    FROM A upd
   INNER JOIN ( SELECT a.ID, COUNT(*) as CountResult
                  FROM A 
                 INNER JOIN B on A.Id = B.Id 
                 GROUP BY A.ID  -- Missed this earlier.
              ) inlineTbl on upd.Id = inlineTbl.Id
```

**EDIT:** Just to explain: what I've done is use an update statement with a join to an inline table counting the number of time each value of A.ID appears in table B).

**EDIT:** Just spotted you changed the second `WHEN` condition to `> 10` so updated my example to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to count corresponding rows in `B` and `if count > 10` then update `A` with 2, `if count > 0` then update `A` with 1, else don't update. The this is what you need:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE ( id INT, c INT )
DECLARE @b TABLE ( id INT )

INSERT  INTO @a
VALUES  ( 1, NULL ),
        ( 2, NULL ),
        ( 3, NULL )

INSERT  INTO @b
VALUES  ( 2 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 3 )

UPDATE  a
SET     c = CASE WHEN b.c > 10 THEN 2
                 WHEN b.c > 0 THEN 1
            END
FROM    @a a
        JOIN ( SELECT   a.id ,
                        COUNT(*) AS c
               FROM     @a a
                        JOIN @b b ON b.id = a.id
               GROUP BY a.id
             ) b ON a.id = b.id

SELECT  *
FROM    @a
```

Output:

```
id  c
1   NULL
2   1
3   2
```

This is just another version:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   a.* ,
                        COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY b.id ) co
               FROM     @a a
                        JOIN @b b ON b.id = a.id
             )
    UPDATE  cte
    SET     c = CASE WHEN co > 10 THEN 2
                     WHEN co > 0 THEN 1
                END
```